# How to hide Excel rows based on the criterion all cells in multiple, non-consecutive columns in that row are blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In Excel, how can I hide rows if and only if all cells in multiple, non-consecutive columns in the row are blank? My worksheet has about 300 columns, so I cannot individually click on every other one each time I want to do this.

I already tried the VBA code below, but it will not allow more than two ranges. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160913
Dim xRg As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRg In Range("B1:B825","D1:D825","F1:F825")
        If xRg.Value = "" Then
            xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else
            xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next xRg
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With UsedRange
        For c = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2
            .AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:="<>"
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Having a lot of columns to check, the following generalized solution will simplify code entry:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Const strcRowExtent As String = "1:825"
  Const strcColExtent As String = "B:BDB"

  Dim boolHideRow As Boolean
  Dim lngFirstColNumber As Long
  Dim rngRow As Range
  Dim rngVisibleRowExtent As Range
  Dim rngColumn As Range
  Dim rngColExtent As Range

  Set rngVisibleRowExtent = Range(strcRowExtent).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  Set rngColExtent = Range(strcColExtent)
  lngFirstColNumber = rngColExtent.Column
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rngRow In rngVisibleRowExtent.Rows
      boolHideRow = True
      For Each rngColumn In rngColExtent.Columns
        If (rngColumn.Column - lngFirstColNumber) Mod 2 = 1 Then
          'Skip every second column
        ElseIf rngColumn.Cells(rngRow.Row).Value2 <> "" Then
          boolHideRow = False
          Exit For
        End If
      Next rngColumn
      If boolHideRow Then Rows(rngRow.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = boolHideRow
    Next rngRow
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Explanation:**

Initially, the set of visible rows is extracted from the full set of rows. This allows for a vast speed improvement.*

The code then loops through this set of visible rows. For each row, it loops through the appropriate columns checking for non-blank values and **not** hiding the row as soon as the first one is found. (Hiding a row is the default action occurring only if all the appropriate columns are blank.)

---

**EDIT #2:**

Second version (v2.1) which also hides columns, as per OP comment below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' v2.1
  Const lngcSkipRows As Long = 4
  Const strcRowExtent As String = "1:825"
  Const strcColExtent As String = "B:BDB"

  Dim boolHideRow As Boolean
  Dim lngFirstColNumber As Long
  Dim rngRow As Range
  Dim rngVisibleRowExtent As Range
  Dim rngColumn As Range
  Dim rngColExtent As Range
  Dim rngCol As Range
  Dim rngVisibleColExtent As Range
  Dim rngCroppedCol As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Hide rows
    Set rngVisibleRowExtent _
      = Range(strcRowExtent).Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    Set rngColExtent = Range(strcColExtent)
    lngFirstColNumber = rngColExtent.Column
    For Each rngRow In rngVisibleRowExtent.Rows
      boolHideRow = True
      For Each rngColumn In rngColExtent.Columns
        If (rngColumn.Column - lngFirstColNumber) Mod 2 = 1 Then
          'Skip every second column
        ElseIf rngColumn.Cells(rngRow.Row).Value2 <> "" Then
          boolHideRow = False
          Exit For
        End If
      Next rngColumn
      If boolHideRow Then Rows(rngRow.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = boolHideRow
    Next rngRow
    'Hide Columns
    Set rngVisibleColExtent _
      = Range(strcColExtent).Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn
    For Each rngCol In rngVisibleColExtent.Columns
      Set rngCroppedCol _
        = rngCol _
          .Resize(Range(strcRowExtent).Rows.Count - lngcSkipRows) _
          .Offset(lngcSkipRows)
      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngCroppedCol) = 0 Then rngCol.Hidden = True
    Next rngCol
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Explanation:**

Turns out extracting the set of visible columns when there are hidden rows (and vice versa) requires a slight modification to the extraction formula.

The code that loops through the set of visible columns is simpler than the one for the rows, as an inner loop is not required. The worksheet function `CountA()` is used instead.

Note that there might still seem to be unhidden columns which are all blank. These have values in hidden rows. Not hiding these columns is intentional, strictly according to your comment.

---

> Note: If you are curious about my variable naming convention, it is based on [RVBA](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp).

*<sub>At the cost of losing the ability to undo rows auto-hidden as the sheet is edited. This can be remedied if required.</sub>

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you! One more addition would be helpful: is there any way I can have Split("B,D,F", ",") automatically list every other column in a range of columns? In my case, that would be ("B,D,F, . . . BDB"), so you can see why I am hoping not to type all of them individually.

Comment: @Claire Updated answer to easily allow a *lot* of alternating columns. Should have posted this originally, but I didn't read your post carefully enough.

Comment: Even more fantastic. Thank you! Now, having applied this solution, I realize that I also (simultaneously) need to hide all columns that are all blank in the range. i.e., columns where all cells are blank from row 5 through row 825. Is there a way to add this in to what you have?

Comment: @Claire I've modified the answer with v2.1 of the the code that hides columns as well as rows.